# Vue 3 call print widow to save pdf file issue

Tags: vuejs3

My problem is how to set up default path when calling print window and save pdf file. That is possible or not? Because of saving wrong file path, I want to set default file path rather than choose file path by users. So any way to do this, if can't set up default path

Comment: Absolutely not possible with Vue or any other JavaScript code, even with WebAssembly - if they run inside a regular browser. Perhaps can be made with a browser extension but you will have better chances with Electron and use Node.js file-system functions.

Comment: thanks, if that is impossible, only what I can do is showing tips to user to avoid saving wrong path.